# Añadir columna con valores dependientes de valores anteriores de esa misma columna

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Intento calcular una nueva columna 'C' en un dataframe cuyo valor depende del valor anterior de esa misma columna.
Por ejemplo: dado el siguiente dataframe:

```
datos = {'A': [10,20,30,40,50] , 'B': [2,4,6,8,10] }
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
df
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que el primer valor de la columna 'C' sea 100, y a partir de ahí quiero que el siguiente valor de 'C' sea  igual a (valor anterior de 'C' + valor de A ) * valor de B

He conseguido resolverlo con un bucle:

```
lista = [100]
for i in range(4):
  lista.append( (lista[-1] + datos['A'][i+1] ) * datos['B'][i+1])
df['C'] = lista
df
```

Quedando así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera saber si podría resolverlo sin utilizar bucle. Resolverlo con el cálculo vectorial de pandas. Tengo muchas filas y quisiera evitar el bucle.

He intentado el siguiente código, pero me devuelve un NaN en el primer número de la columna 'C'

```
df['C'] = 100
df['C'] = ( df['C'].shift(1) + df['A'] ) * df['B']
```

Y también he intentado:

```
df['C'] = ( df['C'].shift(1) + df['A'] ) * df['B']
```

Pero me devuelve un error.

¿Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?
Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma más consistente con Pandas es reemplazar el ciclo explícito por uno implícito mediante `apply()`:

```
acumulado = None
def f(row):
  global acumulado
  ret = 100 if acumulado is None else (acumulado + row['A']) * row['B']
  acumulado = ret
  return ret

df['C'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Pero no nos engañemos, sigue siendo un loop fila por fila, por que en realidad no parece que tu calculo pueda aprovechar alguna vectorización de la librería.